# What is Ios-moe in the libGDX Project Setup?

Tags: android, ios, libgdx

I am planning to create a game for Android, and possibly Ios, using libGDX. On the project setup, for Ios, I am prompted with two options: Ios and Ios-moe. What is Ios-moe? What is the difference between Ios and Ios-moe? Should I use both or just one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ios uses RoboVM, ios-moe uses Multi OS Engine.

LibGDX first used RoboVM for iOS support. When RoboVM was suddenly acquired and its professional development shut down by Microsoft in 2016, its future was vague. So Mario Zechner made some efforts and implemented a backend for Multi OS Engine, which looked promising at that point of time and was acquired by Intel. Because he wasn't able to look into the future, he did not remove the RoboVM backend. A good decision, because in my experiences RoboVM - which was taken over by a volunteer - is more mature than MOE. But you are free to try yourself, both are working.